# How to recognize swipe gestures over a TableView in .NET MAUI?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

I want to allow users to close a page by swiping down.

The page consists of a `Grid` with a `TableView` inside of it.

If I add the `SwipeGestureRecognizer` to the `Grid`, it works as expected, as long as I start swiping on the grid itself (i.e. outside of the `TableView`).

But if I start swiping over the table, nothing happens, even if I add the same type of gesture recognizer to the `TableView`.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the scrollability of the `TableView`.

Is there any way to make a "quick swipe" down trigger the command to close the page, while still allowing the user to scroll the table?

If not, is there a way to disable the scrollability of the table and instead have the gesture recognizer pick up the swipe?

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Down" Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type pages:DetailsPage}}, Path=BackCommand}" />
        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
        <TableView>
            <TableView.GestureRecognizers>
                <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Down" Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type pages:DetailsPage}}, Path=BackCommand}" />
            </TableView.GestureRecognizers>

            <TableRoot>
                <TableSection Title="Type">
                    <TextCell Text="Manufacturer" Detail="{Binding Manufacturer}" />
                    <TextCell Text="Model" Detail="{Binding Model}" />
                </TableSection>
            </TableRoot>
        </TableView>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: For now I'll just place a transparent swipe container _over_ the table, and have the gesture recognizer on the container. Still curious if a swipe recognizer _should_ work on a `TableView` component.

Comment: If it is really difficult to achieve, you may consider changing to the left and right sliding gesture.

Comment: @HongxinSui-MSFT Thanks, but since it's a modal - appearing from the bottom - it doesn't make sense from a UX perspective to close it in a different direction than where it came from. :)

Comment: Have you tried setting TableView.InputTransparent = "True"? It would prevent any interaction with the TableView, including it's child elements.

Comment: @ewerspej Thanks, but that yielded the same result.

Comment: On the Android platform, you may customize a Custom Render, and then set in the OnTouchEvent event to close the page by sliding down. On the ios platform, you can set the tableview.IsScrolledEnabled attribute to false.